# Scatterplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot strings vs integers using matplotlib scatterplot.

My dataset looks like this:

```
      Name               Utilisation
      manhit                  10
      movers                  9
      mayer                 9
      fabcom                8
      freshimp              7
```

I tried with the following code (referred from one of the previous posts) but for some reason it does not work:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter, MultipleLocator
    import numpy as np

    x_data = np.array(dftail.Utilisation)
    print x_data
    y_data = np.array(dftail.Name)
    print y_data

    def ord_to_char(v, p=None):
        return chr(int(v))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x_data, y_data, 'x')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(ord_to_char))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
    plt.show()
```

I would appreciate any advice. Thanks very much.

Comment: A scatter plot is a way to show the relationships between two *numeric* variables, or at least variables that can be ordered and associated with real number values. Why are you trying a scatter plot where one variable is a string? A bar chart would make much more sense.

Comment: "it does not work" it is not enough of a description of your problem.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: It is because i want to see how many Names have different utilisation levels. That was the reason i chose scatter plot.

Comment: A scatter plot has continuous axes. You cannot put categorical variables there.

Comment: why don't use a bar plot?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put categorical values to plot directly. Instead you may plot a list of ascending numbers and later set the ticklabels to the names from the list.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dftail = pd.DataFrame(
        {"Name": ["manhit", "movers", "mayer", "fabcom", "freshimp"], 
        "Utilisation": [10,9,9,8,7]})

x_data = np.arange(len(dftail))
y_data = np.array(dftail.Utilisation)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x_data, y_data, 'bo')
ax.set_xticks(x_data)
ax.set_xticklabels(dftail.Name)
plt.show()
```

[image]